# Can QGIS read/load a zipped shapefile or Geopackage from a URL/URI?

Tags: qgis, geopackage, cloud-gis

Does anyone know if it is possible to load a vector layer in QGIS (not stored in a RDBMS) from a URL/URI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Use the GDAL/OGR VSI (virtual file system) syntax.  For a URI, you would use `/vsicurl`, for a zip you would use `/vsizip` and  you can chain them together, for a zip URI you would use `/vsizip//vsicurl` (note double slash).

So to add the poly layers from:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly.zip 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly_non_conformant.gpkg
```

to QGIS (I have only tested in QGIS 3.0), you would use

```
/vsizip//vsicurl/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly.zip
/vsicurl/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly_non_conformant.gpkg
```

So open the Data Source Manager-Vector (or Layer-Add Layer-Add Vector Layer... (ctrl-shift-v) menu) and you can just paste in `/vsizip//vsicurl/https://url/etc...`

E.g

**Zipped Shapefile**
[image]

**Geopackage**
[image]

**Edit:** I've just found that you can simply paste the URI for a geopackage in the Add Vector Layer... dialog, you don't need `/vsicurl/etc...` but this doesn't work for zipped shapefiles.