# Reading zipped shapefile from URL directly into QGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, shapefile, request, opentripplanner

I need to request a shapefile from an OpenTripPlanner Server and read the file directly into QGIS without saving the file to a disk.

Background and requirements:

- Users system wont be able to write files on their harddrive due to missing permissions
- The request to get the Shapefile requires a header `{"accept":"application/x-zip-compressed"}`, otherwise no zipped Shapefile is returned
- I can only use the "standard" Python libraries. `pip install` or any other external stuff is not possible
- I need to use the zipped shapefile response as the JSON response tends to deliver invalid geometries when adding the parameter `precisionMeters=10` due to a limitation to four decimals in coordinate precision of JSON response (most likely a Bug), while shapefile responses are just fine
- Each response always contains one single zipped shapefile, all named `null.xxx`: `null.prj`, `null.fix`, `null.dbf`, `null.shx`, `null.shp`
- All this is for a [Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OpenTripPlannerPlugin/) I am currently working on

What I have tried:

(The examples below contain a url to a publicly accessible OTP-Server, which is not the one I/users really use. This one seems to return a zipped shapefile without a header given, but this is not the case for all OTP-Servers, so I still need to use the header.)

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/isochrone?fromPlace=60.169,24.938&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&date=2019-11-01&time=08:00:00&maxWalkDistance=500&cutoffSec=1800&cutoffSec=3600'

headers = {"accept":"application/x-zip-compressed"}
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

with ZipFile(BytesIO(response.read())) as my_zip_file:
    for contained_file in my_zip_file.namelist():
        print(contained_file)
        if contained_file == 'null.shp':
            vl = QgsVectorLayer(contained_file, "null", "ogr")
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Which returns an `OGR cannot open error`. So I was thinking I need something like `/vsizip//vsicurl/` as stated at [Can QGIS read/load a zipped shapefile or Geopackage from a URL/URI?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284669/can-qgis-read-load-a-zipped-shapefile-or-geopackage-from-a-url-uri) and [Loading zipped shapefile from URL using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/loading-zipped-shapefile-from-url-using-pyqgis). But the issue is, when I use it as

```py
zipbase = '/vsizip//vsicurl/https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/isochrone?fromPlace=60.169,24.938&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&date=2019-11-01&time=08:00:00&maxWalkDistance=500&cutoffSec=1800&cutoffSec=3600'
shp_name = 'null.shp'
vl = QgsVectorLayer(f"{zipbase}/{shp_name}", 'Test', 'ogr')
if not vl.isValid():
    print ("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

I dont get a valid response due to the missing header. After hours of searching I could find 0 examples or explanations on how to use a header with vsizip.

I also considerd to use a virtual file system, but this seem to require external python libraries.

Is there any way to request a zipped shapefile by using a url+header and reading the file directly into QGIS without writing temporary files on the harddrive?

Comment: Why zipped shapefiles if the service returns nice GeoJSON by default? Test: `ogrinfo -al -so "https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/isochrone?fromPlace=60.169,24.938&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&date=2019-11-01&time=08:00:00&maxWalkDistance=500&cutoffSec=1800&cutoffSec=3600"`

Comment: @user30184 because the Shapefiles do have a higher precision. You can test this by giving the parameter `precisionMeters` with value 10 (this seems to be the highest possible). When using GeoJSON as output, you will get invalid geometries due to a lower coordinate precision, while the results of shapefile responses are just fine.

Comment: Precision does not even seem to have an effect on coordinate precision but to number of vertices, right? Higher precision with shapefiles feels like something that is not planned but just happens. Nice catch from you. Have you considered to make a feature request for fixing the json geometries to OTP project? for me is seems like GeoJSON is meant to be the primary format.

Comment: Perhaps shapefiles and GeoJSON are created with this https://github.com/elefantino/OpenTripPlannerWithChanceOfConnection/blob/7aeacda7040e832a407702e44fd159e40057edbe/otp-core/src/main/java/org/opentripplanner/api/resource/analyst/SimpleIsochrone.java.

Comment: @user30184 don't know about the number of vertices, could be. But in the response JSONs I always get max. 4 decimals as precision, so that is definitely an issue. No haven't considered that yet as OTP 2 is still in development and until now does not even support isochrones. Therefore I dont think a bugreport for OTP 1.5 would make sense currently. Thats why I rather focus on the already existing workaround using the shapefiles which works just fine in my plugin as long as users do have write permissions on C:/users.. folder.

Comment: Compare https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/isochrone?fromPlace=60.169,24.938&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&date=2019-11-01&time=08:00:00&maxWalkDistance=500&cutoffSec=1800&cutoffSec=3600&precisionMeters=10 and https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/isochrone?fromPlace=60.169,24.938&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&date=2019-11-01&time=08:00:00&maxWalkDistance=500&cutoffSec=1800&cutoffSec=3600&precisionMeters=200 The latter gives less vertices.

Comment: @user30184 little misunderstanding :) yes, a higher `precisionMeters` parameter gives less vertices. I thought we are talking about the differences between JSON and Shapefiles, both using `precisionMeters=10`. When using `precisionMeters=10` JSON's tend to give invalid geometries due to the lower coordinate precision while shapefiles dont.

Comment: It seems that OTP output is designed for visualizing the output on a map, not so much to be used as data. Good luck with your shapefile workaround. I did not test the shapefile output because I do not have Poster or other utility installed for adding the headers but I trust you.

Comment: Maybe try the `GDAL_HTTP_HEADER_FILE` config option from the GDAL [VSI documentation](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#network-based-file-systems): "*Starting with GDAL 2.3, additional HTTP headers can be sent by setting the GDAL_HTTP_HEADER_FILE configuration option to point to a filename of a text file with “key: value” HTTP headers*"

Comment: @user2856 after a lot more of research this seems to be indeed the only option left to solve my issue the way I prefer. Unfortunately I could only find 0(!) examples on how to use a header with VSI. So in case you have an example, docs or further explanations on this I'd really appreciate your contribution.

Comment: I got gdal to read the header file and pass the headers when running `ogrinfo` on https://api.digitransit.fi/etc... but couldn't get gdal to read data from the URL, suggest you ask on the gdal-dev mailing list.

Comment: Perhaps also look at where users *can* write, there has to be a writable `%TEMP%` folder somewhere.

Comment: @user2856 thanks a lot for your efforts :) For now I will use the workaround of letting the users choose a custom tempfolder manually if the systems default refuses write access. Lets hope someone has an answer on this someday.

Comment: What if you make use of the ["Download file"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/filetools.html#download-file) tool?