# QGIS Python load shapefile within zip file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to load a shapefile within a zip file, but receive an error

```
zipbase = 'D:\\datasets\\all_clusters_kamloops.zip'
shp_name = 'all_clusters_kamloops.shp'
vl = QgsVectorLayer(f"{zipbase}/{shp_name}", 'all_clusters_kamloops', 'ogr')
if not vl.isValid():
    print ("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Error received in QGIS OGR tab is

```
WARNING    Cannot open D:\datasets\all_clusters_kamloops.zip\all_clusters_kamloops.shp ().()
```

But the following code works fine

```
shpbase = 'D:\\datasets\\all_clusters_kamloops\\all_clusters_kamloops.shp'
vl = QgsVectorLayer(f"{zipbase}", 'all_clusters_kamloops', 'ogr')
if not vl.isValid():
    print ("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the shapefile directly. I have to use the shapefile from within the zip file.
Maybe there is something wrong with the dataset. Here is the link to it
https://mapsafe.xyz/all_clusters_kamloops.zip

Comment: Have you tried the method in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/284697/63384)?

Comment: Yes, thats not a Python script being used. Its manual load.
Please its using a zip file from URL link using vsicurl.